# Enable caching in jetty server

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

I am programming right now a `map-tiles` web application, which should support caching.

**Request cycle**: The browser sends a request to the server, which contains an id of a `tile`, the server loads the `tile` from the database and returns it to the browser.

Most likely the server would get some requests, which request the same `tile`.
So I would like to enable caching on the browser.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For caching whole pages, you may try [ehcache-web](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/modules/web-caching.html).

Its documentation contains [web.xml example](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/modules/web-caching.html#example-web.xml-configuration).

Last available version for maven:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache-web</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```